# MassTransit - Any way to inject parametric settings from appsettings to ConfigureConsumer?

Tags: masstransit

As explained [here](https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/batching.html), I'd like to set batch settings from appSettings.json. Is there any way to do this using ConfigureConsumer by DI?

```
protected override void ConfigureConsumer(IReceiveEndpointConfigurator endpointConfigurator,
            IConsumerConfigurator<OrderAuditConsumer> consumerConfigurator)
        {
            consumerConfigurator.Options<BatchOptions>(options => options
                .SetMessageLimit(100)
                .SetTimeLimit(1000)
                .SetConcurrencyLimit(10));
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add dependencies to the constructor of the `ConsumerDefinition` (the class that has the method shown in the question) as the definitions are resolved from the container during bus configuration. It's a pretty common use case, and easily handled that way.

> The extensions `IOptions` types are good for this, which are part of .NET (`Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` I think).